What can I do to have excel ask for a specific cell to change and add or subtract from a macro I have created?
I am currently creating a PTO schedule for my workplace. We have a small company, yet I am attempting to make it easy for us to handle by using buttons and macros in excel.
I have created a button in my worksheet that subtracts 8 hours (a workday) from a persons hours, yet I would like it to ask which person (row) I would like to adjust and which PTO to pull from (column, being either Personal time or Vacation time).
Personal and Vacation columns
My code right now can only subtract 8 hours from one cell of an employee being his Personal time. I believe I am close, but I need help.
Private Sub cbPlusTimeJR_Click()
Range("f2").Value = Range("f2").Value - 8
End Sub

Above is the code I had used, now I need help beefing it up.

so you  want the number subtracted from column F based on a specific row, correct?  Like if the user clicks on F5, it subtracts 8 hours from F5.  Is that about right?

Essentially yes, I have command button that this is running from. I want to hit that button and it ask which row (the person) and which column (personal or vacation) to subtract 8 hours.

You can use InputBox() to prompt the user for an answer. Then use If/ElseIF/Else to test what they inputted and act accordingly.
Something like:
Private Sub cbPlusTimeJR_Click()

    'Declare a variable to hold column number
    Dim columnNum As Integer
    
    'Declare a variable to hold user response to prompt
    Dim vacOrPers As String
    
    'Get user response using an inputBox
    vacOrPers = InputBox("Do you wish to subtract from Vacation or Personal", "Hour Changes")
    
    'Test what their response was and act accordingly
    If InStr(1, LCase(vacOrPers), "vac") Then
        columnNum = 6 'Column F
    ElseIf InStr(1, LCase(vacOrPers), "per") Then
        columnNum = 7 'Column G
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please enter Vacation or Personal")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Subtract the hours
    Cells(5, columnNum).Value = Cells(5, columnNum).Value - 8
End Sub

The tests in the If portion of the code like InStr(1, LCase(vacOrPers), "vac") are saying "Does the lowercase version of what the user typed contain the string vac?

This works great, would you suggest a good way to add how I could ask which person (column) to choose? Like is this pulling from vacation or personal, ok which person are we editing? That would be the column. At the end you show column 5 being changed, but what if I could as a question of which column to choose instead.

At the end, that 5 is actually the row. Cells(<row>, <column>) is how those parameters are ordered. So you could prompt once again to get which row. rowNumber = InputBox("Which row do want to subtract from") and then use that variable in your last line Cells(rowNumber, columnNum).Value = Cells(rowNumber, columnNum) - 8 (for instance).

There are several ways to go about it, but here is one way to get you started.  It also assumes you have a Sheet2, so update your range reference accordingly.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim someNumber

someNumber = Application.InputBox("What row", "Enter row number", , , , , , 1)

Sheet2.Range("F" & someNumber).Value = "You entered this row"

End Sub

Sorry, just saw you wanted the column and row.  Here is another way, although it seems clunky but I'm including it for learning I guess...:
Dim someNumber
Dim someColumn As Range
Dim columnLetter

someNumber = Application.InputBox("What row", "Enter row number", , , , , , 1)

Set someColumn = Application.InputBox("Select a cell in the column", "Choose column", , , , , , 8)

columnLetter = Split(someColumn.Address, "$")(1)

Sheet2.Range(columnLetter & someNumber).Value = "You entered this row and this column"

End Sub

Maybe it can be simplified????
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim someColumn As Range

Set someColumn = Application.InputBox("Select the cell you'd like to subtract 8 hours from", "Choose cell", , , , , , 8)

someColumn.Value = someColumn.Value - 8

End Sub

Probably should put a healthy dose of error checking / validation around that (making sure they select the right column and row) but this should hopefully get you started...

I see how that enters into another sheet but I want it to change the sheet I am on, as well as change the cell I am searching for. I want it to change the existing number and subtract 8 from it. I've added a picture of the table in my description above.

See my last code block.  Once the dialog box is open, you can change sheets and select cells.  and it'll work.

or just use the solution that @JNevill proposed as that's a much better option.
